# Playing iPhone games with Apple TV & Airplay

Tags: applications, iphone, appletv

I just got an Apple Tv yesterday and I've purchased apps that say they are compatible with Apple Tv for playing games. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get them to work. I've double tapped the home button on my iPhone 4, and it only displays the itunes apple tv / iphone option not the apps apple tv option.

I purchased Kung Fu Rabbit which says its compatible with airplay.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kung-fu-rabbit/id495142468?mt=8

However, I can't get it to work with Airplay at all.

Has anyone figured out a solution to getting games to work with apple tv? 
And does iphone apps / games stream just the sound to the tv, or does it also display the video. I know videos can be streamed to the tv, both sound and visual, but what about games?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what the game is hinting at, but you can mirror your iPad to the AppleTV. Check http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5209?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Only the iPhone4s and the iPad 2 and newer are able to mirror and send images to the ATV - the older iOS devices can send videos and music only through the API's that apple provides.